# Absolute positioning to split title and description

Tags: css, css-position

On this page:

https://www.joshungerdesign.com/packed

I have a 3 image mosaic set up.  I want the title to be at the top of each image and the description at the bottom of each image.  Is there a way to achieve this by writing css to address both the tall image and the shorter one at the same time?

I have tried the following:

```css
.Index-gallery-item-content-heading {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 190px;
}
```

This gives the desired result for the small images but does not work for the tall image.  I'd like all of the images to look like the shorter images with the title at top and description at bottom.

Comment: Please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: The HTML structure is important too... Provide a simple verifiable example here that reproduces the issue and you will get some good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

"Magic numbers" aren't recommended, so try to avoid using specific pixel values if possible. Using ems, %, and vw/vh is a must for responsive design.

But in this case, you can just use `top: 0;` to float an absolute element at the top and `bottom: 0;` to float an absolute element at the bottom (as long as the parent is `position:relative;` of course)

```
.Index-gallery-item-content-heading,
.Index-gallery-item-content-description {
  position: absolute;
}

.Index-gallery-item-content-heading {
  top: 0;
}

.Index-gallery-item-content-description {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Using the top: 0 and bottom: 0 just stacks them and doesn't seem to move the heading into the top if i adjust it.